# The query view generated for the EntitySet is not valid

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting this error, I tried "Regenerate Views" from EF Power Tools and no luck! What could be causing this exception:

***'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. {"The query view generated for the EntitySet 'Generals' is not valid. The query parser threw the following error : The argument type 'Edm.Single' is not compatible with the property 'Price' of formal type 'Edm.String'. Near member access expression, line 3, column 155.."}***

thanks!

Comment: I got this error yesterday on one of our sites, and only solved it by restarting the Web site in question. I've not yet found what the cause was, but it's the first time I've seen it in five years.

Sorry. This comment isn't much help really.

Comment: Found anything? I have a similar issue

Comment: Solution for me was to recreate the Entity Framework project into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this if it can be of help to others.  I know this was almost impossible to find:

[Ef ViewCache](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFInteractiveViews/issues/13)

This explains there is ViewCache table that is created on T4 template generation. That can cause this exact error that was reported in this ticket.  Clearing the ViewCache table could save some major headache troubleshooting this issue if you are sure you have the correct data types / primary key types assigned.